# Creating datasource functionality

Tags: grafana

How do I add data source function to existing default Text panel in Grafana? A there is existing text panel, I want to fetch the value from elastic-search and display it in text panel.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guideline there to provide quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

The text panel cannot fetch data but the [AJAX Panel](https://grafana.com/plugins/ryantxu-ajax-panel) would work as long as the value returned from elasticsearch is text and not JSON.

You can ensure this by setting the format query string to yaml:

`http://localhost:9200/_search?format=yaml`

I answered a [similar question on Grafana's community site](https://community.grafana.com/t/grafana-datasource/987/3).